# Why is my Azure Data Factory data flow failing with 'store is not defined' error?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, pipeline

Getting this error while executing the data flow. I have supplied all the data flow parameters correctly such as PipelineStartTime, PipelineEndTime.

```
Job failed due to reason: com.microsoft.dataflow.Issues: DF-ARG-007 - store is not defined - EXE-0001,Dataflow cannot be analyzed as a graph,[564 737],
source(
) ~> dummy
DF-EXPR-012 - Parameter value for FileName missing - [418 464 564 737],com.microsoft.dataflow.Parameter@597aa1ed,EXE-0001,Dataflow cannot be analyzed as a graph,
dummy derive(
) ~> derivedColumn1
DF-EXPR-012 - Parameter value for PipelineStartTime missing - [418 473 564 737],EXE-0001,Dataflow cannot be analyzed as a graph,
dummy derive(
) ~> derivedColumn1,com.microsoft.dataflow.Parameter@5954ed58
DF-EXPR-012 - Parameter value for PipelineEndTime missing - EXE-0001,Dataflow cannot be analyzed as a graph,com.microsoft.dataflow.Parameter@1819981a,
dummy derive(
) ~> derivedColumn1,[418 473 564 737]
DF-EXPR-012 - Parameter value for NoRowsRead missing - [418 473 564 737],EXE-0001,Dataflow cannot be analyzed as a graph,com.microsoft.dataflow.Parameter@47c44f0c,
dummy derive(
) ~> derivedColumn1
DF-EXPR-012 - Parameter value for Status missing
```

What have I done

The data flow that I created takes the values from the copy activity as parameters and I supplied all the parameter values correctly such as PipelineStartTime, PipelineEndTime,Status, Errors etc. But the data flow is failing by giving this error.
Before giving the errors variable as parameter it was working fine but after that it started to give such errors.

For the errors variable I supplied this value:

```
@concat('"',replace(substring(activity('Copy data1').output.errors[0].Message, 0,100 ),'\r\n|\r|\n' ,'' ),'"')
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: Can you provide the values or dynamic content that you are giving for the PipelineStartTime, PipelineEndTime,Status, Errors parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered the same error (DF-ARG-007 - store is not defined). In my case, I wanted to hand over a name containing a single quote to a data flow from a pipeline For-Each loop (string parameter). After hours of checking and testing I'd now blame Data Factory to potentially screw up it's internal JSON encoding.

**Summary**
The name field I needed to process contained a quote, e.g. "Miles O'Brian":

**Symptom**
Inside monitor something like below is displayed (note the double-quotation of name):

```
{
"dataflow": {
    "referenceName": "PostProcessContact",
    "type": "DataFlowReference",
    "parameters": {
        "accountid": "'12345678-abcd-1234-abcd-123456789abc'",
        "name": "'Miles O''Brian'",
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

**Error**

> Job failed due to reason: com.microsoft.dataflow.Issues: DF-ARG-007 - store is not defined -
> source(
> ) ~> dummysource,EXE-0001,Dataflow cannot be analyzed as a graph,[564 737]
> DF-ARG-007 - store is not defined - EXE-0001,Dataflow cannot be analyzed as a graph,
> operation sink(
> ) ~> parentaccountid,[564 737]

**Potential, related DF-activity**
In the called flow I am using a dummy source without records as I want to build a record solely on the parameters given.

```
"source(useSchema: false,",
"     allowSchemaDrift: true,",
"     validateSchema: false,",
"     inferDriftedColumnTypes: true,",
"     ignoreNoFilesFound: true,",
"     format: 'json',",
"     fileSystem: 'power-platform-dataflows',",
"     fileName: 'nuxnildummy.json',",
"     documentForm: 'singleDocument') ~> dummysource",
```

**Workaround**
In my case, I was able to solve the problem by replacing the single quote in my input string with ‘ which is char(145). Not a nice solution but it works and I carry over the name just for reference.

```
// Previous Assignment: 
"'@item()['name']'",

// Fixed Assignment:
"'@{if(equals(item()['name'], null), null, replace(item()['name'], '''', '‘'))}'",
```

**Conclusion**
Although the workaround is OK in my situation, it is still a bad implementation, therefore @Microsoft:

- Would be great, if this issue will be addressed in a future update.
- Would be great, if an in-memory JSON source would be added which doesn't require one to create dummy-sources in Flowlets (e.g. casting an array of records like [{}, {}, ...] into a useable table).

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered " DF-ARG-007 - store is not defined " , when passing a query statement created in Azure Synapse Piplines into Dataflow
where extra "'" get added like below :

**Example :**
If statement is simple : `"'SELECT * FROM DBO.table'"` there is no issue

But if Statement is

```
SELECT * FROM DBO.table WHERE ModifiedDate >= '1990-01-01 00:00:00.000'
```

Gets converted to

```
"'SELECT * FROM DBO.table WHERE ModifiedDate >= '1990-01-01 00:00:00.000''" -- notice 2 single quotes at the end
```

#### Solution

1. Before sending it to Dataflow convert
   `SELECT * FROM DBO.table WHERE ModifiedDate >= '1990-01-01 00:00:00.000'`
   to  `SELECT * FROM DBO.table WHERE ModifiedDate >= ^^1990-01-01 00:00:00.000^^`

Using : `@replace(activity('Get Select Query').output?.value[0].Query, '''', '^^')` in pipeline Activity

2. In the Dataflow , first remove  all single quotes (') and replace ^^ to back to '.
   `replace(replace($query,"'",""),"^^","'")`

So the query does not break with or without where clause .